# An attempt was made to logon, but the network logon service was not started,

Tags: windows-7, windows, remote

I am remotely connected to a machine on the network and at the same time from that same machine trying to mapp a drive located on another machine

I get the following error

"An attempt was made to logon, but the network logon service was not started"

Would you have any idee please,

Many thanks

Trevor

Comment: +1'd.  Why the downvote?

Answer (score 2):

Open your Windows Start Menu, then search for the application called services.msc, run that, then Find the service under the alphabetically sorted list called Net Logon, right click it, choose start.  If it is set as a disabled service, enable it first, then choose start.